# Combine multiple joins with filters in Vapor

Tags: mysql, swift, join, vapor

In my backend, I have `Post`s and a `PostController`. A post may be `visibleToFriendOnly`.
In `GET /posts`, I want to return all posts that the current user is allowed to see.
The `User` model has a `friends` property, that is a pivot of `User, User` with the columns `userID` and `friendID`.

I currently get posts like this:

```
/// /posts
func all(req: Request) throws -> Future<[Post]> {
    let authenticated = try req.requireAuthenticated(User.self)
    return Post.query(on: req)
        .filter(\Post.visibleForUserType == authenticated.type)
        // FIXME: respect .visibleForFriendsOnly
        .all()
}
```

I'm having a hard time with this because for each `Post`, I'd have to get the `userID` and then the `User` (who is the author) and then query the user's `friends` and see whether the current user is in that list.
Is there a feasible way of doing this? Maybe a join or something?

Comment: I'd suggest to try to query needed data in one request using raw query, then you'll understand if it's possible with Fluent or you need something more

Comment: Could you show some code? I'm relatively new to Vapor & the whole backend/database stuff, especially joins... @imike

Comment: you could find me in Discord as imike#3049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could build a custom raw query like this

```swift
return req.requestPooledConnection(to: .mysql).flatMap { conn in
    defer { try? req.releasePooledConnection(conn, to: .mysql) }
    return conn.raw("""
    SELECT posts.* FROM posts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_friends
        ON (user_friends.userID = posts.userID AND user_friends.friendID = 3)
        OR (user_friends.friendID = posts.userID AND user_friends.userID = 3)
    GROUP BY posts.id
    HAVING COUNT(user_friends.id) = 2 OR posts.userID = 3 OR visibleForFriendsOnly = 0
    """).all(decoding: Post.self)
}
```